# jBPM5 Timer Event xml

Tags: jbpm, business-process-management, bpmn

**Eclise jBPM Designer :**

```
  <intermediateCatchEvent id="_1" name="Timer" >
          <timerEventDefinition>
            <timeCycle xsi:type="tFormalExpression">500###600</timeCycle>
          </timerEventDefinition>
        </intermediateCatchEvent>
```

[image: Eclipse designer]

**Signavio Modeler:**

```
  <intermediateCatchEvent id="_1" name="Timer">
       <timerEventDefinition id="_2">
            <timeCycle id="_3" xsi:type="tFormalExpression">4</timeCycle>
            <timeDuration id="_4" xsi:type="tFormalExpression">500</timeDuration>
         </timerEventDefinition>
      </intermediateCatchEvent>
```

[image: Signavio Modeler]

How to use timer event in jbpm5 ?

Eclipse designer have not timer date and cycle option in gui but xml contains `<timeCycle>500###600</timeCycle>` .

Is following tags supports jBPM5 engine ?

```
 <timeCycle id="_3" xsi:type="tFormalExpression">4</timeCycle>
 <timeDuration id="_4" xsi:type="tFormalExpression">500</timeDuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

jBPM5 supports both timeCycle or timeDuration.  Note that BPMN2 spec defines you should never use them both at the same time, you should select one.  If you only fill in a delay in the eclipse plugin, it should generation a timeDuration, if you fill in a period (as well) it will generate a timeCycle.

Note that it's expecting the delay and period properties to be in the format as defined here:
http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.4/userguide/ch.core-basics.html#sec.timers